# ReferenceError: to is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, postman

When am trying to testing my routes via postman then getting an error like "to is not defined" don't know where am wrong plz help or also tell me what should i do to solve problem

> authRoute.js

This is an authRoute,js file where i added wrote my whole logic and my all secret key i kept my .env files

```
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const _ = require('lodash');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//custome error handler to get useful error from the dataase error
const {errorHandler} = require("./helpers/dbErrorHandling");
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_KEY)

exports.authRoute = (req,res)=>{
   const {name,email,password} = req.body;
   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if(!errors.isEmpty()){
      const firstError = errors.array().map(error=> error.msg[0])
      return res.status(422).json({
            error:firstError
      })
   }
   else{
      User.findOne({
         email
      }).exec((err,user)=>{
         //if user exists
         if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({
               error:"Email is taken"
            })
         }
      })
      //genrate token

      const token = jwt.sign(
         {
            name,email,password
         },
         process.env.SECRET,
         {
            expiresIn:'15m'
         }
      )
      //email data sending
      const emailData = {
         from : process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
         to:to,
         subject: "account activation link",
         html:`
         <h1>Please Click link to activate</h1>
         <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/user/activate/${token}</p>
         <hr/>
         <p>This email contain sensitive info</p>
         <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>`
      }

      sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent=>{
         return res.json({
            message: `Email has been sent to ${email}`
         })
      })
      .catch(err=>{
         return res.status(400).json({
            error: errorHandler(err)
         })
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: the error is correct. You have `to:to,` and have not defined the `to` variable after the colon

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: sir plz tell me how to solve that problem can u help me

Comment: @MonuPatil Just define `to` in your code or hardcode it as `to: "you@yourdomain.com",`

Comment: to:to were are you getting value of to from